# does [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation:] get a new instance of the cell?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell with a UISwitch set as the accessoryView. When i change the text in the data model that corresponds to a specific cell, I reload the indexpath for the particular row and section. However, inspecting the method cellForRowAtIndexPath, I see that a different instance of the cell is retrieved with

```
                cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"mySpecificCell"];
```

Now my question is, is there any way to retrieve the UISwitch state before reloading the cell (i loose the state since its a different instance)?

I dont want to add yet another Array to my data model to hold the "Switch States". This is one solution but not really elegant.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: So currently how you know what is state of switch?

Comment: Well before the reload where i set the new text for that cell, i have a reference to the cell, so i added a method to get the state like such:

[cell isSwitchOn];

so i can get the state before the reload. The issue is, how do i get the state inside the method cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: So it mean that. The switch is begin always off, and when you change it you want hold state of switch and don't want store in model?

Comment: Right, i mean storing it in the data model inside yet another array is an option, i was just wondering if there is any other way. Is there not a way to get the current cell instance inside the method CellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: If you don't want store in model. You can using an another array for store state. But it bad. In my opinion  I think don't have any better option except store state in model.